# google analytic 4 (ga4) return Invalid JSON payload

Tags: json, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying get data from google analytics api 4 (ga4), I send the request  in postmen:

my url:

`https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet`

method: POST

body:

```
{
    "reportRequests": [
        {
            "viewId": "376027054",
            "dateRanges": [{
                "startDate": "2023-01-03",
                "endDate": "2023-01-0"
            }],
            "pageSize": 1,
            "metrics": [
                {
                    "expression": "ga:hits"
                }
            ],
            "dimensions": [
                {
                    "name": "ga:date"
                }
            ],
            "segments": [],
            "filtersExpression": ""
        }
    ]
}
```

but I got invalid json:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unexpected end of string. Expected an object key or }.\n\n^",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The analytics reporting API will only allow you to extract data from universal analytics accounts.

You need to use the data api to extract data from ga4 accounts